Unyson Backups Extension cURL Error and Issues with Importing Old Workreap Demo Content
I'm currently working on a WordPress site using the Workreap theme, and I'm encountering several issues that I need help with.

Unyson Backups Extension cURL Error
I'm getting the following error when trying to access the Unyson Backups Extension:

Failed to access GitHub repository "ThemeFuse/Unyson-Backups-Extension" releases. 
(cURL error 28: Failed to connect to github-api-cache.unyson.io port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached)

Details:
Theme: Workreap
Unyson Version: 2.7.3.1 (latest version)
Steps Taken:

Uploaded the Unyson Backups Extension files via FTP.
Clicked "Activate" within the WordPress dashboard.
After activation, the entire WordPress site became inaccessible.


Importing Old Workreap Demo Content

My main goal is to import the old demo content for the Workfleek theme, specifically the home page 4 demo content. However, after importing the demo content available with the Workreap theme, it didn't include the specific demo content I need.
I've been informed that Workreap offers both an old and a new version, and I'm looking to use the old version's demo content.
Questions:
How can I resolve the cURL error 28 related to the Unyson Backups Extension?
What is the correct method to activate the Unyson Backups Extension without making the site inaccessible?
How can I import the specific old demo content (home page 4) for Workreap/Workfleek?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
Oday Rafeh
Steps Taken on the Unysen plugin:

Uploaded the Unyson Backups Extension files via FTP.
Clicked "Activate" within the WordPress dashboard.
After activation, the entire WordPress site became inaccessible.

What I've Tried from the theme side:
I followed the usual steps to import the demo content, but the specific "home page 4" demo content isn't available.
I also tried to resolve the cURL error by adjusting server settings, but the issue persists.
